# Bitwise OR XOR on arrays returning a 0 array

Tags: c++, arrays, sdl, bitwise-operators

I am wanting to get an array representing all of the keys just pressed(not held down, just pressed, like you were typing) by the user. I figured the best way to do this was to have 3 arrays - currentKeyboard(cK), previousKeyboard(pK) and in the function getting the currently pressed keys, returnKeyboard(rK).

Assuming cK and pK looks like this:

```
 pK = [1 1 0 1 0 1]  
 cK = [0 1 1 0 1 0]
```

A bitwise OR on the two should return

```
rK = cK | rK //[1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

And by using a bitwise XOR on rK and pK, it should give me the keys currently being pressed that were not being pressed before.

```
    [1 1 0 1 0 1]
XOR [1 1 1 1 1 1]
------------------
    [0 0 1 0 1 0]
```

However, when I run my code it appears that I am always getting back a 0 array. 
(I am assuming I made no mistakes with my bitwise arithmetic; if I did please let me know!)

Here is my code for getting the pressed keys:

```
Uint8* KeyboardController::getPressedKeys()
{
    Uint8* r_Keyboard= new Uint8[283]; 
    //Loop through every SDL_SCANCODE(starting at 4) and set them to 0 in r_Keyboard
    for (int i = 0; i < 283; i++) {
        r_Keyboard[i] = 0;
    }

    //If there is a previous keyboard to compare to
    if (m_preKeyboard) {
        //Now, compare m_curKeyboard to m_preKeyboard and set 1 in r_Keyboard to any differences (OR pK and cK, then XOR pK with the resultant of OR)
        for (int i = 4; i < 283; i++) {
            r_Keyboard[i] = m_preKeyboard[i] | m_curKeyboard[i];
            r_Keyboard[i] = m_preKeyboard[i] ^ r_Keyboard[i];
        }
    }

   //Testing - am I just getting back a 0 array? 
    for (int i = 0; i < 283; i++) {
        if (r_Keyboard[i]) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }

    return r_Keyboard;
}
```

And my function that sets m_curKeyboard and m_preKeyboard:

```
void KeyboardController::Update()
{

    if (m_curKeyboard) {
        m_preKeyboard = m_curKeyboard;
    }

    m_curKeyboard = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
}
```

And here is the main loop code:

```
            bool isOn = true;
        while (isOn)
        {
            //Pump events(Needed for SDL_GetKeyboardState to work)
            SDL_PumpEvents();

            keyboard->Update();

            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

            Uint8 *keysPressed = keyboard->getPressedKeys();

            if (keysPressed[SDL_SCANCODE_A]==1) {
                printf("A key pressed!\n");
            }
            if (keysPressed[SDL_SCANCODE_S]==1) {
                printf("S key was pressed!\n");
            }
            if (keysPressed[SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE]==1){
                isOn = false;
                //delete keysPressed;
            }


        }
```

Now, if I comment out either the OR or XOR line in my getPressedKeys() function, I will get output back from the program. However, it's futile since it will spam the output seeing that a key is being held down, rather than being pressed.

Comment: You're returning a reference (pointer actually) to a temporary object (`r_Keyboard`).  `r_Keyboard` goes out of scope when `getPressedKeys()` returns.  Any use of it after that is undefined behavior.

Comment: Whoopsie, thought I changed that back to `Uint8* r_Keyboard = new Uint8[283]`. Fixed that, thanks for catching it.

Comment: You'd still be better served with `std::vector` instead of managing your own memory.

Comment: And as much as I'd like to, SDL_GetKeyboardState does not return an std::vector but a pointer to a Uint8 array. Maybe in the future I'll write something that takes the returned Uint8 array and feeds it into a vector, complete with smart pointers, but as of right now I'd like to understand why this is returning a 0 array rather than the correct array. I am positive I've figured it out(I am positive the problem exists in my Update procedure)

Comment: If you have two arrays (even if they aren't vectors) you can still use `std::transform` + `std::logical_or<int>` as shown in my answer below.  Also, in your update, you leak `r_Keyboard` every time the function is called.

Comment: My only advice left is to step through with the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess `SDL_GetKeyboardState` always returns the same pointer. So this:

```
if (m_curKeyboard) {
    m_preKeyboard = m_curKeyboard;
}
```

is really a no-op. You'd need to allocate and copy an array:

```
void KeyboardController::Update()
{
    if (m_curKeyboard) {
        if (!m_preKeyboard)
            m_preKeyboard = new Uint8[283];
        for (int i = 0; i < 283; i++) {
            m_preKeyboard[i] = m_curKeyboard[i];
        }
    }

    if (!m_curKeyboard)
        m_curKeyboard = new Uint8[283];
    auto curKeyboard = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 283; i++) {
        m_curKeyboard[i] = curKeyboard[i];
     }
}
```

Comment: Close enough! After doing a bit of research, I found that in addition to renaming SDL_GetKeyState() to SDL_GetKeyboardState, they also changed the return value from `Uint8*` to `const Uint8*`.
Additionally, I misinterpreted their notice on SDL_GetKeyboardState. It only needs to be called once, for assignment. SDL_PumpEvents() is the one that actually updates the array. changing my update function to copy the values of m_curKeyboard into m_preKeyboard and calling update BEFORE SDL_PumpEvents(), everything works great now.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily using the standard template library.  Here's a small example.  Also note, you need to fix your returning a reference to a temporary (see my comment on the question).  Moving to `std::vector` (as in this example) will make your life much easier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // previous keyboard presses
    std::vector<int> prev_kb{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};

    // current keyboard presses
    std::vector<int> next_kb{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};

    // combined keyboard - sized to the size of next
    std::vector<int> combined(next_kb.size());

    // apply the logical_or<int> algorithm to each keyboard press
    std::transform(
        prev_kb.begin(),
        prev_kb.end(),
        next_kb.begin(),
        combined.begin(),
        logical_or<int>());

    // print to verify it worked
    std::for_each(
        combined.begin(),
        combined.end(),
        [] (int c)
        {
            cout << c << ' ';   
        });
    return 0;
}
```